# Metro app localization issues (Windows 8)

Tags: localization, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a metro style app created from a Visual Studio 11 template. I created `strings\en\Resources.resx` and `string\cs\Resources.resx`. I have an English Windows 8 installation set to czech (cs) locale. When I run the application, English resources from `strings\en\Resources.resx` are always picked up. Date formatting is also in English locale (`DateTime.ToString()` showing English month names). When I delete `strings\en\Resources.resx` the `string\cs\Resources.resx` gets picked up and everything works just fine.

Can anyone help? I also tried to set the Neutral language in the assembly settings to Czech and edited `DefaultLang` in `.csproj` but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this on MSDN:

Test the app for the other languages.

1. Open the **Control Panel**, and select **Clock**, **Language**, and **Region** >
   Change **display language**.
2. Note that the language that was displayed when you ran the app is
   the topmost language listed that is English, German, or French.
       If your topmost language is not one of these three, the app falls
       back to the next one on the list the app supports.
3. If you do not have all three of these languages on your machine, add
       the missing ones by clicking Add a language and adding
           them to the list.
4. To test the app with another language, select the language in the
   list and click Move up until it is at the top. Then run the app.

Hope this helps?

Comment: you are right, my bad, system localce is something other that language priority